# how to get satellite menu working

Tags: android, android-layout

Just trying to mess around with some new things. I was wanting to get this [satellite menu](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu)
working but I am not really sure how (noob question I know). I imported both into eclipse and tried to make the one a library of the example, but that didnt get it working. Could someone specify all of the things I would need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 components to what I believe you're describing:
1. Import Code
2. Set library as a library
3. Reference library from your main project

The only thing you didn't mention is the reference (#3). To do this:
Right-Click the project that needs to reference the library 
-> Click "Properties"
-> Click "Android"
-> The bottom half of this screen shows included libraries. Click the "Add" button to the right.
-> Your library should show up select it
-> Click "OK"